# How can I send UIEventTypeRemoteControl events?

Tags: iphone, ios, events

It's really easy to listen to UIEventTypeRemoteControl events, to respond to play/pause commands etc. However, what I need to do it be able to **send** these events to the device, so my app can control music playback of any other app that's currently playing music. Is this possible? Searching the docs didn't turn up anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible in non jail broken device.

Comment: Sadly, this is my conclusion as well.